# Match strings in 2 columns of different sheet and copy it

Tags: string, vba, excel, match

I'm very new to VBA so need help... please help me experts..

I have data in column B sheet 1 which is something like this - 123alina09032015 &
I have data in column A sheet 2 which is like this - alina.

The data is huge and keeps adding every month. So what I want is a VBA code to match the words from column A sheet 2 and column b sheet1 and paste it to the adjacent cell in column c of sheet 1

I have a code but that only finds the exact match and pastes it to column c in sheet 1. Here is the code:

```
Sub CopyBasedonSheet1()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Sheet1LastRow = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet2LastRow = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For j = 1 To Sheet1LastRow
    For i = 1 To Sheet2LastRow
        If Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(j, 1).Value = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(i, 4).Value Then
            Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(j, 3).Value = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value
        Else
        End If
    Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

Looking forward to your answer

Comment: Do you only want the first match? Your current routine keeps looking after it finds something. Should subsequent matches be stacked into adjacent columns? Could you edit your description so that the columns you use match the column within the code (or edit the code)?

Comment: How about using InStr() ?

Comment: Yes I used InStr() and it solved my problem.. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

The worksheet function `=Find("abc","123abc456")` will return the start position of "abc" in the "123abcdef" string, so 4 in that case.  If the second string doesn't contain the first one, then it returns the #Value error.  That can be checked with the `=IsErr(A1)` function.  That's if you're doing it on the sheet.

To do something similar in code, `= InStr(.cells(a,b), .cells(c,d))` will return the same 4 if the value in the SECOND cell is found in the FIRST cell entered (so the opposite order of arguments from the worksheet Find function).  But, the VBA function doesn't generate an error, but rather a zero result, if the one string isn't found inside the other.

It sounds like the OP cares that the one string contains the other, but not exactly where within the string the other is found.  So instead of testing the the cells are equal, check if `InStr(worksheet().cell(), worksheet().cell()) > 0`.  When true, the one value is found within the other, and you can perform the `Then...` as written.